# How do I strikethrough text in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, text-formatting

Basically I want to <strike>strike through</strike> some text; how can I do this?

Comment: There use to be a Greasemonkey script that added button for this, but Google broke it when they updated Gmail.  Not sure if there are any that work now.

Comment: There is script: [`userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/show/57725`](http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/show/57725). Tested working.

Comment: Note to Googlers: Ignore the top answers and just use `Alt + Shift + 5` instead.

Comment: Or `cmd + shift + x` for Mac users @Pikamander2

Answer (score 235):

Ok, I have discovered a simple way. Copy <strike>this text</strike> and paste into your e-mail. Edit the text. Voila!

Comment: The only bummer is this also carries over the color and font. I've found the extension @GHelper posted to work much better as it just adds a button to the text formatting toolbar in Gmail.

Comment: After pasting the text, select it and hit *Ctrl-Shift--* (Ctrl-Shift-Minus) to shrink it down to Gmail's default font.

Comment: it doesn't work for me (FF)

Comment: i already had a substantial amount of text typed that I wanted to strikethrough without needing to edit.  I pasted it into a ckeditor instance, applied the strikethrough, then copied it back into gmail and it worked!

Comment: haha, you made my day the craziest and most efficient answer ever

Comment: @Michael - If you've already written a bunch of text, you can paste with ctrl-shft-V to paste while maintaining the style of the text you're pasting into.

Comment: SHIFT-CTRL-- reduced the font size of *everything* in Chrome for me. (Had to restore it to the default zoom using CTRL+0). Instead did the same by selecting via the TT font icon, selecting "Normal".

Comment: Go to recent answers and upvote this comment so others also go to recent answers.

Answer (score 137):

This may not be for everyone (I work in web development), and it's slow, but if you use Chrome or Chromium you can edit the HTML directly and it works fine.

1. Right-click on the text you want to strike out
2. Choose 'inspect element'
3. The inspector will bring up that text - right click on it and choose 'edit html'
4. Wrap the text you want to strike out with `<strike>text</strike>`

[image]

Comment: The third step is important. Editing the tag element with that text and adding the `<strike>text</strike>` there results in `<strike>text</strike>` being the text in the email (tags visible, without the formatting), and the HTML for it is `&lt;strike&gt;text&lt;/strike&gt;`.

Comment: Such a great answer. This should be the accepted one!

Comment: alternatively you can add `text-decoration: line-through;` to the elements style using the dev tools

Comment: Use [`<s>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/s): the current version of the obsolete [`<strike>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/strike).  ([`<del>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/del) should be used exactly for deletions from documents, as in a *diff*;  that is something you would usually not format manually. (@jaepage))

Comment: This technique works (I used the `<s>` form suggested by @AaronThoma) and TBH it's more memorable than Google Sheets' Option-Shift-5 or Google Docs' Cmd-Shift-X, neither of which works in Gmail.

Comment: This solution is awesome, with a small caveat: to identify the block easily it needs to be on its own line lie it the example. If the word you want to strike in a sentence/block then you will make sure that you find the specific work in the block/div  and add the <del></del> around only that word.

Answer (score 67):

While this is a very old query, I have found a nifty way to work on it, thus posting it as a solution.

There is a shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd> to toggle the strike-through. Select the text to strike through, click once <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd> the text is stroked, click once more the text is back to normal.

For Mac: <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>

Comment: Wow, you made my day ! Works perfectly on Chrome. And yes, this should be the accepted answer. Thx !

Comment: This is the answer, glad I scrolled down, thanks!

Works in all browsers I've tried, seems to be an undocumented gmail feature.  Looks like gmail uses the same editor as docs, and that shift+alt+5 is a google docs feature.

Comment: for me it replaced the text with "fi"

Comment: Confirmed for Firefox on MacOS High Sierra 10.13.6 - definitely the correct answer.

Answer (score 14):

Personally, I type emails that need more formatting options in the [CKeditor demo](http://ckeditor.com/latest/samples/index.html). Then, I copy the final text into Gmail - the formatting is retained.

Comment: Hehh, a smart, instant, minimalist idea, +1! :) (It's kind of unfair use of that demo, though, if I'd go by Kantian ethics... ;-o )

Comment: Yeah, someone should definitely write a userscript or extension to replace Google's Inbox and Gmail textareas with CKeditor...

Answer (score 12):

There is no native way to do it, so you either do it in Word (or any other text editor that supports it) and then copy/paste the text in the compose window or you install a browser add-on.

Comment: "or you install a browser add-on" ... such as?

Comment: @endolith such as [StrikeThrough for Gmail](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/strikethrough-for-gmail/ajociahccjjemoemghnnlejboonninbl). (Disclaimer: I haven’t used it.)

Comment: *StrikeThrough for Gmail* is long defunct according to its [reviews](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/strikethrough-for-gmail/ajociahccjjemoemghnnlejboonninbl/reviews). ( @Alex )

Answer (score 10):

On Mac in Google Chrome, select the text, and hit <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd>.

Comment: Works in Safari too

Answer (score 9):

As of **January 2019**, you can use new **Formatting options - Strikethrough** (<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>5</kbd>):
[image]

Source: https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2019/01/new-gmail-compose-formatting-and-download-options.html

Answer (score 3):

I thought it would be clever to create a bookmarklet in Chrome that would modify the style of selected text using JavaScript.

Unfortunately, I couldn't get that to work, but if you're familiar with the console, you can paste this line into it to strikethrough any selected text:

```
window.getSelection().anchorNode.parentNode.style.textDecoration = "line-through"
```

To get to the console, you can right click anywhere in the HTML document of the Chrome Browser and choose "Inspect Element," or you can press "option / command / J" at the same time on a Mac machine.

F12 or "control - shift - J" opens up the console on PCs.

Once you've done this, the console will remember your command, and you can press the up arrow to cycle through past console commands. When you return to this particular one, just press enter again to apply it.

Answer (score 3):

January 22nd 2019, Google announced:

We're adding three new features to Gmail:

- Shortcut to undo/redo in the compose window
- Shortcut to strikethrough text
- Ability to download messages as .EML files in rfc822 format from Gmail on the web

from [New Gmail compose formatting and download options](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2019/01/new-gmail-compose-formatting-and-download-options.html) in the official G Suite Updates blog.

Answer (score 0):

Command (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>) + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>.

Comment: On what OS/browsers have you tested this? This doesn't work for me on Chrome/Windows.

Comment: Chrome on Mac OS. Just tested again and it is working. Make sure you select the text before hitting Cmd + Shift + X.