# Gmail reply feature erases previous conversation recipients and subject line when clicking trimmed content icon to view email history

Tags: gmail, email

When you reply to a Gmail thread, the previous conversation is trimmed.

Suppose A wrote email on 01-08-2022 to: B and cc:C

Next day, B reply to all and added new cc: D

To D, preceding conversation will look like this

On Mon, 1 Aug 2022 at 11:27, A  wrote

This means D does not know to whom original emails were addressed. In a long-email chain, it would be difficult to understand who is replying to whom. (Subject lines are also not shown though that is not a issue for me specifically)

However, this behaviour is not seen when forwarding email. Therein, full details are retained

From: A

Date: Mon, 1 Aug 2022 at 11:27

Subject: subject-line

To: B

Cc: C

So, my question is how to retain such details when replying in Gmail?
If not possible, is this something that irks other gmail users also or just me?

Comment: After typing the question, just found a partial workaround where at least I can retain email recipients & subject line here https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/154970/286720. Simple click forward then change it to reply/reply-all. It will retain the formatting of forward but change it to a reply. Do note that original attachments would get unattached if you required them.

Comment: It seems above comment is slightly wrong. One need to click forward, then click edit subject. Only then will it retain all details. However, need to fill TO & CC recipients manually. The original attachments will be retained so need to remove them if not required again.