# Is there a setting in Gmail to keep the "recipient block" when replying to an email?

Tags: gmail, delete

In the Gmail web app, when I Reply or Reply-All, Gmail removes what I will call the "recipients block" from the quoted text that shows the following information ***for the email that I am replying to***:

```
    From: Sendy McSenderstein <smcsenderstein@email.com>
    Sent: Tuesday, September 6, 2023 12:00 PM
    To: Recip Tieup Airdowon <recip@email.com>
    Cc: Other Recipient <orecipient@email.com>
    Subject: Gmail recipient block deleted on reply
```

Gmail DOES keep the "recipient block" when I forward an email.

I'm aware that I could use a third party POP or IMAP program, and that's just what I used to do. The problem is that my company recently decided to do away with Outlook and wants everyone to use the Gmail web app. Outlook would keep the "recipient block" whenever I would reply, reply-all, or forward an email.

I have tried digging through all the Gmail settings and many web searches with different ways of phrasing the same question, but I've only found [one other post on SE regarding this issue](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/165920/gmail-reply-feature-erases-previous-conversation-recipients-and-subject-line-whe), and it was not answered.

**So, is there a Gmail setting somewhere to retain the "recipient block" on reply and/or reply-all?**